# Reordering a Datagridview on Cell Value Change

Tags: vb.net

I am currently having issues when trying to reorder a datagridview after a cell value has changed. After a value in a specific column has changed I want to resort the columns based on this new value. However it is not quite sorting correctly.

For example lets say I am starting with the datagridveiw in the picture below.
[image]

I then make a change to the Line column of the first row and renumber it to 8. At this point I would like to move row 1 to where the current row 8 is and every other row would then be renumbered.

I have implemented the following code to do this.

```
    Dim OuterSourceRowIndex As Integer
    Dim InnerSourceRowIndex As Integer

    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        For Each rowOuter As DataGridViewRow In dgvReceive.Rows
            For Each rowInner As DataGridViewRow In dgvReceive.Rows
                OuterSourceRowIndex = rowOuter.Index
                InnerSourceRowIndex = rowInner.Index
                If rowOuter.Cells(0).Value >= rowInner.Cells(0).Value Then
                    dgvReceive.Rows.RemoveAt(OuterSourceRowIndex)
                    dgvReceive.Rows.Insert(InnerSourceRowIndex, rowOuter)
                End If
            Next
        Next

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvReceive.Rows
            row.Cells(0).Value = row.Index + 1
        Next
    End If
```

When I attempt to actually make the change though I end up with the following where line 1 is actually moved to position 7. All of this is happening on the CellValueChanged Event
[image]

I apologize if this has been answered before. I was not able to find anything that was quite like this. Thank you for any help given.

Comment: What is the DataSource of your DGV? If it's a DataTable, you could use the `DataTable.DefaultView.Sort` property (e.g., `...= "Line ASC"`). The DataGridView control also has a `Sort()` method (e.g., `dataGridView1.Sort(Column1, ListSortDirection.Ascending)`). Note that the Column's data type determines the sort order.

Comment: @Jimi it is an unbound datagridview. I will look into the sort method however from the very quick implementation I tried of it I was not able to implement the column renumbering the way I would like.

Comment: I probably read it to hastly. You have a problem with renumbering the cells. If you modify a value in the range `((A - 1) : (B - 1))`, the distance is `D = (B - A)`, the direction is `a = (V(b) > V(a) ? 1 : -1)`. So, If 8 becomes 2, renumber rows from `(2 - 1)` for `((8 - 1) - (2 - 1))` rows. Since `V(b) > V(a)` (`8` > `2`), you add +1 to the values in range, then set the new value to the row that is changed and Sort().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably made this more complicated with those double loops.  Also, you should avoid a For-Each loop since you are modifying the collection as you loop over it.

Not much on error checking, but this is a simplified version.  It removes the row you changed, inserts it in the proper place, and then renumbers everything.

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
  RemoveHandler dgvReceive.CellValueChanged, AddressOf dgvReceive_CellValueChanged
  Dim thisRow As DataGridViewRow = dgvReceive.Rows(e.RowIndex)
  dgvReceive.Rows.Remove(thisRow)
  dgvReceive.Rows.Insert(CInt(thisRow.Cells(0).Value) - 1, thisRow)
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvReceive.Rows
    row.Cells(0).Value = row.Index + 1
  Next
  AddHandler dgvReceive.CellValueChanged, AddressOf dgvReceive_CellValueChanged
End If
```

I added the RemoveHandler and AddHandler lines to prevent too many fireworks from firing when you change all those cell values when you renumber the line items.

Comment: This works perfectly. and you are right the for-each was a bad idea that made trying to step thru this portion of the code.

Comment: I never thought of removing and adding handler when I know unintentional events would run. Interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @Mary It would be better to put this code in a Try-Catch-Finally block, with the AddHandler put in the Finally block, just to make sure the event subscription is never lost.